# Is it possible to code IR Blaster in android using titanium?

Tags: android, titanium

I have a need to use IR Blaster in my app to control my television? Can this be done using Appcelerator titanium for android phones?

Comment: It would be helpful to break this question down and research it in parts and post your findings.  Ie, 1) what is required to control this IR blaster device?  Does it have an Android API or do you push special data to the headphone jack?  2) Are there any related methods (perhaps for generic audio) passed through in titanium 3) what is involved in adding custom native extensions to a titanium project - is that "supported" or do you have to do something ugly like unpack the apk it builds, add more classes, and repack?

Comment: @ChrisStratton It says [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html#44-ir-blasters) that android 4.4 has added support for IR Blasters. I will try and gather more information. Thanks.